# update two columns failures - failed to set two columns to null

Tags: sql, oracle

Below SOL doesn't work:

```
update table1 
   set col2=null, col3=null 
 where id=195366
```

If I just update one column, it works

```
update table1 
   set col2=null 
 where id=195366
```

Comment: might be coll3 have have contstraint not null

Comment: Maybe col3 is NON NULLABLE?

Comment: Can you paste the error output here?

Comment: I checked: col3 doesn't have 'not null' restriction.

Comment: no any error when i update it from sql developer.

Comment: That isn't posting the _exact_  error message? How are people meant to help you when they don't k ow what's wrong?

Comment: "*Doesn't work*" is not a valid Oracle error message.

Comment: @a_horse: I once saw some software spit out "Well, bugger me!" - you'd be surprised what some developers put in their code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of reasons why that might fail. `col3` may have a `NOT NULL` constraint <sup>(a)</sup>, `col2+col3` may be the composite primary key, there may be a trigger on the table that disallows both being `NULL` and so on.

Short of seeing all the database setup (table definition, triggers and so on) and the actual error you're getting when you try, it's a little hard to be definitive.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Keeping in mind that the statement is atomic - either both will be set to NULL or neither will be changed, there is no halfway state possible in a proper transactional database.

Comment: the issue is caused by trigger restriction.